# Why is numpy np.insert method behaves differently when the obj parameter is an integer or a sequence?

Tags: python, numpy

The np.insert function is used to insert values along a specified axis in an array.

I am trying to understand why the outputs are different when I use a sequence instead of integer for the obj parameter.

```
   arr_a = np.random.randint(1,10, size=(3,3), dtype=np.int64)
   arr_a
   >>> array([[2, 3, 8],
             [6, 7, 2],
             [1, 9, 4]])
   
   arr = np.insert(arr_a, [1], [[5],[5],[5]], axis=1)
   arr
   >>>array([[2, 5, 3, 8],
             [6, 5, 7, 2],
             [1, 5, 9, 4]])

   arr_b = np.insert(arr_a, 0, [[5],[6],[7]], axis=1)
   arr_b
   >>>array([[5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 8],
            [5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 2],
            [5, 6, 7, 1, 9, 4]])
```

I understand that,

Using a list allows you to specify multiple indices at which values will be inserted.
Using a single value allows you to specify a single index at which values will be inserted.

Comment: Screenshots of code are not copyable. Please create a [reprex] with the code *as text*.

Comment: To format as code, either add four spaces before every line, or add a line containing three backticks (`\``) before and after your code. See [formatting help](/help/formatting)

Comment: The [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) contains a note pointing out this behavior: _"Note that for higher dimensional inserts `obj=0` behaves very different from `obj=[0]` just like `arr[:,0,:] = values` is different from `arr[:,[0],:] = values`."_

Comment: Thank You @pho, I am having hard time to understand what that statement means.

Comment: @pho to be fair, that note doesn't actually explain anything, It just tells us "that" the behaviour is wildly different, but it doesn't link to anywhere that explains _what_ the difference is or _why_ that difference exists.

Comment: `np.insert` is a complex python function (not compiled).  It tries to handle a number of different inputs.  Some of the details are best understood by examining the code.  Basically it creates a return array with the deduced shape and dtype, and then fills in values from the source array and new values.  But keep in mind that indexing is different with a scalar and a list, so it's not surprising that `insert` should also differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [172]: a = np.ones((3,4),int)
```

Simple 'scalar' insert - put `2` in all rows of a new column before `a[:,1]`:

```
In [175]: np.insert(a,1,2,axis=1)
Out[175]: 
array([[1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Insert 3 numbers in that column:

```
In [176]: np.insert(a,1,[2,3,4],axis=1)
Out[176]: 
array([[1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 3, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 4, 1, 1, 1]])
```

But if there's a mismatch between rows and insert values:

```
In [177]: np.insert(a,1,[2,4],axis=1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[177], line 1
----> 1 np.insert(a,1,[2,4],axis=1)

File <__array_function__ internals>:200, in insert(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:5406, in insert(arr, obj, values, axis)
   5404 new[tuple(slobj)] = arr[tuple(slobj)]
   5405 slobj[axis] = slice(index, index+numnew)
-> 5406 new[tuple(slobj)] = values
   5407 slobj[axis] = slice(index+numnew, None)
   5408 slobj2 = [slice(None)] * ndim

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,1) into shape (3,1)
```

Note that this is a `broadcast` error.  It's taking the values as a (2,1) array, and trying to put it in a column that is (3,1).  When there are 3 values, it works: (3,1) into (3,1).

On other hand if we specify a list insert location, it puts both values in:

```
In [178]: np.insert(a,[1],[2,4],axis=1)
Out[178]: 
array([[1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Or with 2 columns:

```
In [179]: np.insert(a,[1,0],[2,4],axis=1)
Out[179]: 
array([[4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
       [4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
       [4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]])
```

But 2 columns, and 3 values don't `broadcast`:

```
In [180]: np.insert(a,[1,0],[2,4,3],axis=1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[180], line 1
----> 1 np.insert(a,[1,0],[2,4,3],axis=1)

File <__array_function__ internals>:200, in insert(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:5432, in insert(arr, obj, values, axis)
   5430 slobj[axis] = indices
   5431 slobj2[axis] = old_mask
-> 5432 new[tuple(slobj)] = values
   5433 new[tuple(slobj2)] = arr
   5435 if wrap:

ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (3,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (3,2)
```

We/I could examine the code to see how it constructs the `slobj` index array, and how it tweaks the `values` list/array.

In two of the above cases, we can 'recover' the `values` with the matching scalar/list indexing:

```
In [187]: np.insert(a,1,[2,3,4],axis=1)[:,1]
Out[187]: array([2, 3, 4])

In [188]: np.insert(a,[1,0],[2,4],axis=1)[:,[2,0]]
Out[188]: 
array([[2, 4],
       [2, 4],
       [2, 4]])
```

The docs makes a note of this common pattern

```
Note that for higher dimensional 
inserts obj=0 behaves very 
different from obj=[0] just like 
arr[:,0,:] = values is different 
from arr[:,[0],:] = values
```

### edit

Curiously when I try to insert 2 columns with the scalar or list, I have to specify different `values` shapes:

```
In [193]: np.insert(a, 1, np.zeros((2,3),int), axis=1)
Out[193]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]])

In [194]: np.insert(a, [1], np.zeros((3,2),int), axis=1)
Out[194]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Ultimately, the answer to `why` questions is - because the developer(s) chose to do it that way.  We (non-developers) can only look for patterns and/or consistency, we can't give a definitive answer.

### from the code

Under examples:

```
>>> np.array_equal(np.insert(a, 1, [1, 2, 3], axis=1),
    ...                np.insert(a, [1], [[1],[2],[3]], axis=1))
```

and

```
    values = array(values, copy=False, ndmin=arr.ndim, dtype=arr.dtype)
    if indices.ndim == 0:
        # broadcasting is very different here, since a[:,0,:] = ... behaves
        # very different from a[:,[0],:] = ...! This changes values so that
        # it works likes the second case. (here a[:,0:1,:])
        values = np.moveaxis(values, 0, axis)
```

For our 2d, axis=1, case, makes `values` into a 2d.  This `moveaxis` is equivalent to a transpose.  So for a scalar `obj`, `values` of (3,) becomes (1,3) and then (3,1) (a 'column vector')